# Capture a photo by invoking Camera and save it to the SD card or sql database in worklight

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I saw various links about using native camera and capturing photo for our own applications. But I am suffering with saving the photo either to the device or to store in a database. I have codes for including the file path and etc.. But I am not aware of where to include those in the program. Please help me with it.

I have used the following URL for camera implementation
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html

I am using worklight and apache cordova for invoking the camera.

```
File sdDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

where to include the above line in the script?

How and where to include the img tag in the HTML?

How to convert the image to base64 and store it in the database?

---

I have attached the coding below. Please cross check the functions I have used and help me with it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
 <title>Capture Photo</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.0.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

var pictureSource;   // picture source
var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 

// Wait for PhoneGap to connect with the device
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

// PhoneGap is ready to be used!
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}

// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
  // Uncomment to view the base64 encoded image data
  // console.log(imageData);

  // Get image handle
  //
  var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

  // Unhide image elements
  //
  smallImage.style.display = 'block';

  // Show the captured photo
  // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
  //
  smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}

// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
  // Uncomment to view the image file URI 
  // console.log(imageURI);

  // Get image handle
  //
  var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

  // Unhide image elements
  //
  largeImage.style.display = 'block';

  // Show the captured photo
  // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
  //
  largeImage.src = imageURI;
}

// A button will call this function
//
function capturePhoto() {

String fileName = System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg";
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
fileUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);



  // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
 navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50 }); 

function onSuccess(imageData) {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
}

// A button will call this function
//


// Called if something bad happens.
// 
function onFail(message) {
  alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button> <br>

    <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
    <img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This would require an elaborate answer , have u used the navaigator.camera.getpicture() as said in the link properly ? can u take  a picture ! if yes , please share your code in the question provided. Am i correct in assuming u want to get the uri of the image captured? u want the location of the image in your phone and u want to show your image on the screen and/or save it into database? Now you have to imaplement either websql/sqlite storage Insert operation . Revert back with edit on your question , with code samples

Comment: @IamKarim1992 please find the coding below and help with it.

Comment: @IamKarim1992 you are right I want to display the image in the HTML and also to store in an online data or mysql. If the picture captured is in a new page, then it would be better.

Comment: first dix your code to take a picture , a lot of examples can be found as to how to worl with navigator.camera.getpicture(onSuccess,onError,options), then work from there .

Comment: I am able to take the  picture but not able to display it or say it as i mentioned before. @IamKarim1992

Answer (score 1):

I was also struggling with same problem and found the solution by defining the the image uri before starting the camera activity as shown below:

call the below method on some click when you want to start camera.

```
private void getImages() {
    String fileName = System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg";
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
    fileUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

I have given the image name as the current timestamp so that each time the image will have a new name and there will be no redudency. also no need to change the image to base64 simple change to bitmap and display to your image view, if you want to store the imageview to database then save the uri as String datatype in above line of code the variable fileuri is String type, if you want to store the image in your sqlte then save that fileuri.

As you already define the image uri, so there is no need to get the uri from onActivityResult also the image will automatically saved in your phone without calling onActivityResult.

Only to get the preview or showing the image to your imageview you have to call onActivityResult().

To show the image in yourimageView write follow the below code.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == HomeActivity.RESULT_OK) {
            try{
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
        // images
        options.inSampleSize = 8; 
        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),
                options);

        yourimgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
            }
        } else if (resultCode == HomeActivity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // user cancelled Image capture
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // failed to capture image
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

}
```

Comment: Thank you @HAXM the coding which you have given for the yourimageView is in Java. Can you please say in the scripting language JS?

Comment: Sorry buddy i know java only :(

Comment: Find the coding above and help me as much as you can @HAXM

Comment: well i checked your code and found every thing correct if you use only the two methods capturePhoto() and onSucess() but as i'm a naive in scripting language i can't say you should use the other functions or not.

Comment: Thank you @HAXM :)

Answer (score 0):

i have impalmented this using File API plugin of cordova ,

Here is the link https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
    or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
    distributed with this work for additional information
    regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
    to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
    "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
    with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
    software distributed under the License is distributed on an
    "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
     KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
    under the License.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <!--
        Customize this policy to fit your own app's needs. For more guidance, see:
            https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md#content-security-policy
        Some notes:
            * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
            * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
            * Disables use of inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
                * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
        -->

        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
                <button style="width:30%;" onclick="pickImage()">Clean Data</button>
                <p id="lastPhoto"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function pickImage(){
                var lastPhotoContainer = document.getElementById("lastPhoto");
                var doc= document.getElementBy
                window.imagePicker.getPictures(
                function(results) {
                    console.log(results);
                        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        var imageUri=results[i];
                        console.log('Image URI: ' + results[i]);
                        lastPhotoContainer.innerHTML = "<img src='" + imageUri + "' style='width: 75%;' />";
                        }
                    }, function (error) {
                        console.log('Error: ' + error);
                }
            );
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

this simple example takes a single image from the local storage and shows it on the screen of the app , u can go ahead and convert the image from the uri to base64 and use it as u like .Now thsi would populate the already taken picture into html ..Hope this helps.

Comment: I would work with this and return back to you @IamKarim1992